# C# addition operator overloading

Tags: c#, syntax

I am trying to port some C# code to another language (C# is not my usual language).

I have a vector class (`cpVect`) that overrides the '+' operator twice:

```
    public static cpVect operator +(cpVect p1, cpVect p2)
    {
        return new cpVect(
            p1.x + p2.x,
            p1.y + p2.y
            );
    }

    public static cpVect operator +(cpVect p1)
    {
        return new cpVect(
            +p1.x,
            +p1.y
            );
    }
```

I can see that a new instance of `cpVect` is returned from both methods but I'm trying to figure out how one would call these methods in a code example (so I can make sure I'm porting them correctly). For instance, does the second method add p1 to the receiving cpVect?

```
v3 = v1 + v2   <-- does this call method one above?
v1 = v1 + v2   <-- does this call method two above?
```

Thanks

Comment: As an aside, now would be a good time to learn about .NET naming conventions, and apply them to your code. Also note that you're not *overriding* anything - you're *overloading* operators.

Comment: Point taken  - I meant overloading :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both call the *binary* operator. The *unary* operator would be called if you only had one operand:

```
v3 = +v1;
```

The unary `+` operator is rarely useful, to be honest - but it's mostly there for symmetry with the unary `-` operator.

Comment: Forgot about the unary operator. There isn't one in the language I'm porting to (Xojo). Thanks.